# Rails console search path and Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-console

I need to add a new user to my app's Postgres `User` table located in the `test` schema. When I access the console, rails automatically sets the search path to `"$user",public` and the new user record is saved to the `public` schema, not the `test` schema. Is there a way to add records to the `User` table within the `test` schema using the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *rails automatically sets the search path to*

No, it's not Rails - it's Postgres doing that. It's the default search path defined in Postgres. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH

If you want a different search path for that user, use `alter user` to change the user's search path, e.g.:

```
alter user foo set search_path = 'public';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the rails-console is very well suited to do administrative tasks. You are also specifying the schema in the `database.yaml` I guess you would need to create a new connection in your console.